# systemd timer, how can I restart the service after power loss?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I'm experiencing with systemd timers to launch a service every day at let's say 7am. This service launch an application that must run continuously until 10pm. So if the application crashes, the service must restart it. The service is stopped at 10 by crontab, that also shutdown the system.

I'm using a timer with OnCalendar and Persistent=true which works, but I cannot ensure that if there is a power loss (system is restarted by BIOS when power is back) after 7am the service is started, because the timer already successfully triggered at 7am and so will wait until next day..

I cannot run my service at boot because if the system can start before 7am (power loss during night) and so also the service will start, I don't want it before 7am..

Any idea?

Comment: "but it only works if 7am is not passed yet" ... So you want it to run at 7 am or if the system rebooted?

Comment: The service must run from 7 am to 10 pm, regardless of the system reboots in the middle. I cannot start at boot because the whole can start (power outage for example) at 5 am...and I don't want the service start before 7

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the timer is scheduled with OnCalendar, what is the last run status of the timer after such missed event? It's the LAST column of `systemctl list-timers` output.

If it reads 'n/a' then the timer was never triggered before, or it's last run state was cleared and so it won't be run at boot.

Comment: Yes, I use OnCalendar. It's not a missed event, because at 7 am the timer triggered.. but let's say that after there is a power outage..

Answer (score 0):

<s>Current solution I found is this..
Delete *stamp* file in `~/.local/share/systemd/timers`.
Then restart the timer.</s>

[Source][1]
"These are zero length files which mark the last time each timer was run. If deleted, they will be reconstructed on the next start of their timer."

[1]: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers

I tought I've found a solution, but then realized it doesn't work when there is a powerloss after 7am...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

```
[Timer]
#Execute job if it missed a run due to machine being off
Persistent=true
#Run 120 seconds after boot for the first time
OnBootSec=120
```