# systemd does not restart service after power loss though Restart=on-failure

Tags: raspberry-pi, systemctl

I have a weather station service, *weewx*, on a **Raspberry Pi** 3. When there is a **power cut** (thunderstorm), the Pi reboots when the power is back, but *not* the service weewx which remains in "inactive" status:

```
    ● weewx.service - LSB: weewx weather system
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/weewx; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

Yet, the configuration of the service has the "Restart=on-failure" option which should handle the case to my understanding. How can I **get the service to automatically reload**? Note that it restarts without any issue manually if I do systemctl start weewx.

```
[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/weewx
Description=LSB: weewx weather system
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
After=remote-fs.target
After=time-sync.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
SuccessExitStatus=5 6
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/weewx start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/weewx stop
ExecReload=/etc/init.d/weewx reload
```

Thanks!

NB. [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599363/systemd-timer-how-can-i-restart-the-service-after-power-loss) is specific to *timer*, which is not my case.

Comment: What weather station and how do you access it? If via network, you select Before multi-user which doesn't have network ready.

Comment: the weather station is on a local network, with an IP address like 192.168.0.x

Comment: @stoney I'm editing the configuration to replace with Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target. It's a good idea. Even if I'm not sure this will solve the problem however, because weewx can start without any problem if there's no network. It's just that it won't be able to see the weather station. + the error was service "inactive" which doesn't seem to match completely.

Comment: Check for any typos or syntax errors in unit file. Also ensure that all dependencies are available and correctly configured.